# No equivilant of 'type="email"' for contenteditable elements?

Tags: html

I have a `div` with `contenteditable` where users can type a list of email addresses. Kind of like how an email application allows entry of multiple recipients and resizes automatically based on how much space it needs.

Since it's meant for emails, I was looking into a way to use the 'email keyboard' layout when the field is focused, like `<input type="email" />` would (or any of the other [Input Type attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp) often have their own software keyboard layout on Android and iOS).

But it looks like this isn't possible?

Comment: Not everything that runs on a computer or smartphone is made with HTML. And HTML fancy inputs are complex JavaScript libraries that wrap regular `<input>` fields with some extra markup.

Comment: I know but I'm writing this thing in html. So I'm looking for an html solution. I don't use a library that does fancy stuff with inputs, I intentionally use a div with contenteditable=true because I want it be 1 line but resize when needed. As far as I know, that requires this approach?

Comment: I'm not proficient with contenteditable but HTML forms have never been particularly powerful (not even in HTML5) so you'll possibly need JavaScript. You can get a better overview if you try something: edit your question (you don't need to save changes) and start typing a new tag in the "Tag" section. White at it, right click to use your browser's "Inspect element" feature. You'll be able to see the `<input>` element and the additional mark-up, carefully styled to look one single thing.